# Interviewer wrongly called and accepted me, then really accepted me

Tags: interviewing, mistakes

I am a backend developer with good history, knowing little about front-end. In previous weeks I wanted to switch my job. I took 3 days off, and arranged 5 or 6 interviews in those days. Interviews went well and three companies, which had the best offer, called and told me I am accepted and whenever I go there I can sign contract with them. I chose the best offer and rejected other two.

Next day I resigned from my current job and called the new company and told them I will go there next week to sign the contract. while I was speaking with them on the phone, I realized they wanted to call some other person with the same lastname with me, In a front-end role. I immediately told the person on the line. He became nervous, told me he will call me back. 5 minutes later he called me again and told he now remembered me and He thinks I am totally fit for that situation, as I am totally able to learn fast and do the front-end job (which I can in two or three weeks).

This didn't satisfy me, And later that day, I called him again and told him If he accepted me, just because the mistake and because he thinks I resigned my current job for them, then I really do not have a problem and I can find another job in less than a day. He then assured me and told firmly he totally remembered me and thinks I will be a good fit, and I can do backend too while I will learn their front-end technology (reactJS).

Tomorrow I have to visit them and sign the contract. I'm still highly in doubt wether I message him that I was chosen mistakenly and prefer not to work there, Or ignore my doubt and trust him.

My question, is which decision is more professional. Specially if anyone ever experienced the same situation (it's not common situation, I know), can guide me better about consequences of going there.

Comment: You applied to the job.  Now you have the job.  Is there a reason except for “sour grapes” you are considering not taking it?

Answer (score 4):

You need to do whatever you need to do to be employed. If that means trying to accept one of the other two jobs, or signing the contract with the one that might have accidentally hired you; you need to take those steps.

Your mistake was telling the other two companies no, and resigning from your current job, before signing the contract. There is still a chance that they can say no, before you sign the contract.

Only you can judge if the long term prospects in the company will allow you to move to a role you want in a reasonable amount of time.

Neither option is more professional. They apparently made a mistake. You jumped the gun. And now you both have to figure out what to do.

Another reason for waiting to reject or quit, is that until you get the contract in writing there can be issues in the contract that can delay your start date, or cause you to walk away from the offer. I have seen issues with pay, work location, and shift requirements that have been showstoppers.

Comment: I resigned, not only for them, because I didn't want to work for my current company. I was going to resign anyway, but maybe if there wasn't their call, I would resign next month.

Comment: I agree, I shouln't have said no to the other companies. What annoys me, is I am 10 in back-end. If he employ me for front-end, I will start job in 5 and get benefit of 10, while I can get real 10 elsewhere, Its not wether he is ok with this or not, which he is ok, Its more about should I go 5 and get 10 benefits, or I should go where I am best of myself. Sorry if I explained complicated

Comment: *Its more about should I go...* We can't really tell you what to do - you have to decide what outcome you want, and which job will help you get there.

Comment: You are right. right now, here was best place to ask for some more thought. I can detele if it doesn't fit.